# How to solve ValueError Assign problem in Django?

Tags: python, django

I created a system with Django. In this system, user uploads an excel table and I creating a new customer from that excel. But in this excel I have 2 important columns. They are entity and parent. I want to when a user uploads this excel table but If there is an entity or parent that is not registered in my database, I want to create it and then save it. I user get_or_createe for that but I am getting an error:

> ValueError at /customers/upload Cannot assign "(<ParentCompany:
> TESTP>, False)": "Customer.parent" must be a "ParentCompany" instance.

How can I solve it?

**views.py**

```
def customer_excel_upload(request):
    current_user = request.user
    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)
    company = userP[0].company
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerExcelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_excel = form.save()
            new_excel = new_excel.excel
            df = pd.read_excel('C:/fray/otc/'
                               +
                               new_excel.name,
                               index_col=0,
                               engine='openpyxl')
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                if row is not None:
                    new_customer = Customer()
                    new_customer.customer_name = index
                    country = Country.objects.get(country_name=row['Country'])
                    new_customer.address = row['Address']
                    new_customer.customer_number = row['Customer Number']
                    new_customer.phone_number = row['Phone Number']
                    new_customer.email_address = row['Email Adress']
                    new_customer.credit_limit = row['Credit Limit']
                    new_customer.currency_choice = row['Currency choice']
                    new_customer.risk_rating = row['Risk rating']
                    parent = ParentCompany.objects.get_or_create(parent=row['Parent Company'],
                                                                 company=request.user.company)
                    entity = Entities.objects.get_or_create(entities=row['Entity'], company=request.user.company)
                    new_customer.parent = parent
                    new_customer.entity = entity
                    new_customer.country = country
                    new_customer.company = company
                    new_customer.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CustomerExcelForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'customer_excel_upload.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250),
    ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entities, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class ParentCompany(models.Model):
    parent = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)
class Entities(models.Model):
    entities = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_or_create` doesn't return an object directly, as the error message says. You can check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). It returns a tuple of `(object, created)`.

Yours is returning correctly

```
(<ParentCompany: TESTP>, False)
```

You just need to get the first part.

you can change your `get_or_create` statements to get the first like this:

```
ParentCompany.objects.get_or_create(parent=row['Parent Company'], company=request.user.company)[0]
```

note the `[0]` on the end.